# How can I fix this error?: Type '(String!, args: CVaListPointer)' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'

Tags: swift, realm

I have this code:

```
let articleConflict = Article.objectsWhere("title = 'test'")
```

I am getting this error:

```
Type '(String!, args: CVaListPointer)' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you linking `RLMSupport.swift` as noted by Realm's Swift installation instructions? http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.87.4/#installation

Comment: It appears that I didn't link that file for this project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're getting that message (what Xcode version are you using, btw?) but variadic C functions aren't supported in Swift. You'll have better luck creating an NSPredicate instance and then calling the `objectsWithPredicate` method:

```
let testPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "title ==[c] 'test'")
let articleConflict = Article.objectsWithPredicate(testPredicate)
```

Comment: I don't understand why one should prefer "objectsWithPredicate" over "objectsWhere".  p.s. Thanks for your help.